# Saga not running when action creator being called inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I created a saga which listens to an action of type "GET_CHARACTER", it'll then hit an api and send the data to a reducer.

I try to call the action creator in componentDidMount, the action occurs (I can see it in dev tools) but the saga isnt being called.

The saga works for sure as I've tried testing the action creator by calling it when a button is clicked, the saga runs and I get my data.

It just doesn't work when I try call the action creator in componentDidMount.

Is this something to do with Saga being a middleware?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you dispatch your action. There is likely an error in your code. Please provide relevant code snippets.

Comment: I have the same problem... did you find any solution in the meantime?

Comment: ...I solved it in my case, added an answer in case it applies to problems experienced by others too, since this ranks high google when searching for the issue

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue and in my case it was due to having a blocking `yield call(...other thing)` in my root saga **before** the code setting up listening for the actions triggered in `componentDidMount`, so it executed in an order like this: (1) in root saga that other thing started running (2) in `componentDidMount` the action that was supposed to trigger my other saga got dispatched (3) only after the other thing finished, did the rest of the root saga ran, and registered the listener for the action that was supposed to be triggered by action from `componentDidMount`, but by this time it was too late, sagas don't start for actions triggered before their registering to run at that action.

Hope it makes sense...

Here is the relevant code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.doStuffThatTriggerMySaga();
}
```

...then in sagas:

```
function* mySaga(action) {
  // ...
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield call(doOtherStuff); // this was the problem
  // ...
  yield takeEvery(ACTION_TRIGGERING_MY_SAGA, mySaga)
}
```

**The solution is to refactor the code to eliminate the "blocking" `yield call(doOtherStuff);` call and make that other stuff also run triggered by an action, like have a `yield takeEvely(OTHER_STUFF_ACTION, doOtherStuff);` and figure out where it makes sense for you to trigger that action.**

Comment: hi @NeuronQ could you please look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75732330/saga-watcher-function-not-being-called-after-re-login-when-called-under-componen